# Chain Rule of Complex Differentiable functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I want to formulate and prove chain rule for $\mathbb C-$ differentiable functions,

I think it should be $(f\circ g)'(z)=f'(g(z))g'(z)$

But how to prove it ?

Edit: 
I proved it using $\frac{f(g(z))-f(g(z_\circ))}{z-z_\circ}= \frac{f(g(z))-f(g(z_\circ))}{g(z)-g(z_\circ)} \frac{g(z)-g(z_\circ)}{z-z_\circ}$

But my Prof. want a different proof.

Comment: You prove it exactly like you prove the chain rule for functions $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$. The quotient-free definition of differentiability is more convenient than looking at the difference quotients for proving the chain rule.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I proved it like that but my prof. want a different solution.

Comment: I want a short one as mentioned in question.

Comment: $h:U\to\mathbb C$ is differentiable at $z\in U\subseteq \mathbb C$, open, with derivative $\eta\in\mathbb C$ if and only if $h(z+d) = h(z) + \eta d + o(d)$ for $d\to 0$. Select the right $h$ and $\eta$...